# How to prevent Polkadot{.js} extension from injecting all addresses into the site's JavaScript context

Tags: polkadot-js, account, polkadot-js-extension, metamask

By default the Polkadot{.js} extension injects all addresses that have been imported into the browser wallet when a connection is requested by a website.

In comparison, the Metamask extension on Ethereum/Moonbeam/Astar allows you to choose which addresses you want to share with the application:

[image: Metamask connect address]

How would this be accomplished with the Polkadot{.js} extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Polkadot{.js} extension doesn't offer site-specific account permissions the same way that Metamask does.

However, you can set the global visibility of each individual account which will prevent the account information from being injected into the website when a connection is made.

To hide an account click on the eye icon (it will become red and crossed out when the account is hidden):

[image: Polkadot hide account]

Note that you will have to toggle the visibility settings every time you want to change which accounts are visible to an application.

Comment: Shame that there is no way to make it site-specific. It would be nice if there were some 'visibility templates' that could be attached to specific dapps.

Comment: You should open a feature request, sounds like something that is easily programmable.

Comment: There is an open request for proposals on the W3F grants program repo that addresses this and other privacy related features of polkadot.js: https://github.com/w3f/Grants-Program/blob/master/rfps/privacy-enhancement-polkadot-extension.md. If anyone is interested in implementing it, you can submit an application on that repository.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so all I'm left with is to answer:

I implemented this feature a couple months ago https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/pull/1068 I published an article about it too: https://blog.chainsafe.io/polkadot-js-extension-new-privacy-feature-3f80900589ec

It will be part of the next release in production hopefully in the coming weeks. Releases of the extension are taken very seriously because the time it takes between the submission and going live can be very long (like a week). If you push something that hasn't been sufficiently tested, leaving users without a fix for a week is disastrous.